# Why does this error appear when I open a new page in my flutter app?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a simple TTS flutter application, and I made a settings page with sliders to change the pitch, rate and volume. But when I press the button to go to that page, I get the error:

Failed assertion: line 162 pos 15: 'value != null': is not true.

Any idea how to fix this?

Here is the code for the settings page:

```
  double volume;
  double rate;
  double pitch;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Settings'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Slider(
          value: pitch,
          onChanged: (newPitch) {
            setState(() => pitch = newPitch);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: It's extremely simple, yet  I keep getting the error.

Comment: What is on line 162 in your code ?

Comment: I don't even have 162 lines in my code!

Comment: Its from material/slider.dart btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

line 162 states that `min` property of `Slider` must not be null. So as `max` and `divisions`. You must pass them to make it work. Take a look:

```
 const Slider({
Key? key,
required this.value,
required this.onChanged,
this.onChangeStart,
this.onChangeEnd,
this.min = 0.0,
this.max = 1.0,
this.divisions,
this.label,
this.activeColor,
this.inactiveColor,
this.mouseCursor,
this.semanticFormatterCallback,
this.focusNode,
this.autofocus = false,
}) : _sliderType = _SliderType.material,
   assert(value != null),
   assert(min != null),
   assert(max != null),
   assert(min <= max),
   assert(value >= min && value <= max),
   assert(divisions == null || divisions > 0),
   super(key: key);
```

Comment: I think this would be right, but it still doesn't work...

Comment: check out can your `pitch` value be null? Is it possible?